# Customizing warden strategies for omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, warden

I'm using devise to authenticate users with facebook, and I'm trying to set up handling of facebook deauthorizations.

I have a user model with an attribute called `authorized`, which gets updated when the facebook callback for the deauthorization occurs. All of that works.

I want to subclass the warden strategy to include checking of the user's authorization state, but I can't figure out which warden strategy to subclass.

If I remove all of the other authentication options provided by devise, and just use

```
devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [ :facebook ]
```

there are no warden strategies defined when I run `Warden::Strategies.send(:_strategies)`.

Which warden strategy should I be subclassing to get omniauth behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific strategy for omniauth.  I can't see one anyway. However, if you want to check the attribute on each request (e.g. they de-authorise your app whilst logged in to it), then you should instead override `active_for_authentication?` in your User model.  This is called as part of the check for each request by the Warden hook code in `lib/devise/hooks/activatable.rb`.  Don't forget to call `super` and also implement an inactive message if you want.  See the doc:

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Authenticatable

Comment: Glad to hear it; happy to help.